# How To Successfully Update User Profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Im Trying To Update My User Profile But I Received An Error How Do I Fix This ?

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

```
newUsersReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.EmailTextField.text!, "ProfileImageUrl": ProfileImageUrl!])
```

This Is The Full Code For Context

```
let uid = user.uid
            let storage = Storage.storage()

            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://tvmassmedianetwork.appspot.com").child("profile_Image").child(uid)
            if let ProfileImge = self.SelectedImage, let imagedata = ProfileImge.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
                storageRef.putData(imagedata, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                    return
                }
               let ProfileImageUrl =    metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL
                  let ref = Database.database().reference()
                  let UsersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)

                  let newUsersReference = UsersReference.child(uid)
                    newUsersReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.EmailTextField.text!, "ProfileImageUrl": ProfileImageUrl!])
```

Comment: I did it & its Nonnull

Answer (score 1):

Now you have 3 optional values `self.UsernameTextField.text`, `self.EmailTextField.text` and `ProfileImageUrl`

When you use `!` the exclamation mark you are forcing unwrap optional value assuming "**its never going to be nil**", So if you access a `nil` value the app will crash. 
So Never use `!`. I'd rather sprinkle `if let` and `guard let`

```
 if let username  = self.UsernameTextField.text, let email = self.EmailTextField.text,let imageProfileUrl = ProfileImageUrl {
        newUsersReference.setValue(["username":username, "email": email, "ProfileImageUrl": imageProfileUrl])
    }
```

OR do the following

```
newUsersReference.setValue(["username":self.UsernameTextField.text ?? "", "email": self.EmailTextField.text ?? "", "ProfileImageUrl": imageProfileUrl ?? ""])
```

so that you will set default value empty string `""` in case value is `nil`

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. Could you please extend it and add details about unwrapping in particular.

Comment: I have edited the answer with more details, I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("PATH\FileName")
```

If you want to save only one image in your storage, give it a fix name.If each user can have a profile image(in most cases), you can use this

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unwrapping optional forcefully?.

You can use `if-let` here.

```
//if ProfileImageUrl has value, it will be set in `newUsersReference`.
if let img = ProfileImageUrl {
    newUsersReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.EmailTextField.text!, "ProfileImageUrl": img])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to unwrap variable with conditional statement

```
//if ProfileImageUrl has some value then execute statement

if let imageProfileUrl = ProfileImageUrl {
    newUsersReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.EmailTextField.text!, "ProfileImageUrl": imageProfileUrl])
}
```

Comment: though it is a bad practice to force unwrap values. Check other answers above.

Answer (score 0):

This is where part of the issue is

```
let UsersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)
```

you're creating a firebase reference to

```
root/users/uid
```

then you're attempting to read

```
let newUsersReference = UsersReference.child(uid)
```

which is

```
/root/users/uid/uid
```

I think you want something more like this - typed on my iPad so don't copy paste but it should be close.

```
func updateUserProfile() {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    let uid = currentUser.uid
    let storage = Storage.storage()

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://tvmassmedianetwork.appspot.com").child("profile_Image").child(uid)
    if let ProfileImge = self.SelectedImage, let imagedata = ProfileImge.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        let uploadTask = storageRef.putData(imagedata, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }

            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                return
            }

            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                let thisUserRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
                thisUserRef.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.EmailTextField.text!, "ProfileImageUrl": downloadURL])   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other two answers have some good info as well - please handle options as... optional - they could be nil so you need to account for that. Force unwrapping them with a ! can be dangerous - keep your code safe and handle nil accordingly.